# GWT check if mobile browser can open/download pdf file

Tags: java, gwt, pdf, user-agent

i was wondering if `GWT` can detect if browser (mobile/desktop) can open pdf files?

in my application, clicking a `gwt-Button` (named PDF) will generate a pdf report. the pdf creation happens on the server-side (php), and all i have to do is to call a specific action. The server includes `application/pdf` as its `Content-type`.

now, testing my PDF button in `iPad/iPhone`(simulator) opens a new tab which displays the PDF report generated while on an `Android` emulator (an [Android SDK for Mac](http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r20.0.3-macosx.zip) run on eclipse), it downloads the `.php` that process the pdf report not the pdf file generated. so i decided to view my PDF button only to those browser that can open `PDF` file. how to do this?

upon checking the user-agent:

iPad simulator = `Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 4_3 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8F192 Safari/6533.18.5`

for my Android emulator =`Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1; en-us; sdk Build/JRN83C) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30 Safari/6533.18.5`

Comment: "it downloads the .php that process the pdf report not the pdf file generated": this does not sound right, i think you should check why that happens, ie why php is not executed

Answer (score 1):

You probably have some error in your code, because a .php should never be downloadable!

For your pdf-detection problem check this jquery-plugin:
http://plugins.jquery.com/browser/

You can insert it in your html and get its result via a native method in GWT. Not the cleanest solution, but it should work as you need it.